# Valgrind invalid write, after struct code addition

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, valgrind

For school I have to initialize a map with cells.
While analyzing my code with Valgrind, I ran into some problems.
The initialize function I used worked previously, but stopped functioning after adding two additional interger pointers and an integer. The memory is allocated dynamically, and the bug shows up in the part that was previously also there, this has got me stumped. The error that occured was the following:

```
==4877== Invalid write of size 4
==4877==    at 0x401723: initialize_map (list.c:312)
==4877==    by 0x400B99: main (initialization.c:14)
==4877==  Address 0x550deb8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2,584 alloc'd
==4877==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4877==    by 0x4016EA: initialize_map (list.c:306)
==4877==    by 0x400B99: main (initialization.c:14)
==4877== 
==4877== Invalid write of size 4
==4877==    at 0x40172D: initialize_map (list.c:313)
==4877==    by 0x400B99: main (initialization.c:14)
==4877==  Address 0x550debc is 4 bytes after a block of size 2,584 alloc'd
==4877==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4877==    by 0x4016EA: initialize_map (list.c:306)
==4877==    by 0x400B99: main (initialization.c:14)
==4877== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:277 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.
```

the initialize code is the following:

```
worldmap* initialize_map(game_settings* settings)
{   
    int maxplayers = 10;
    int rows = settings->rows;
    int cols = settings->cols;
    worldmap* world = malloc(sizeof(worldmap)); //free in cleanup_map
    if(world != NULL)
    {   
        world->rows = rows;
        world->cols = cols;
        world->map = malloc(sizeof(cell)*rows*cols); //free in cleanup_map
        for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols;j++)
            {
            cell* cell = index_map(world, j, i); //cell* is world->map + offset
            cell->type = CELL_DIRT;
            cell->owner =  0;
            }
        }
        world->players = 0;
        world->score = NULL; //NULL pointer, since this pointer set in a later function
        world->playerturns = NULL; //NULL pointer, since this pointer set in a later function
        return world;
    }
    else{printf("No world found.\n");}
}
```

The additions to this `initialize_map()` code are: `int maxplayers`, `world->players`, `world->score` and `world->playerturns`, the rest of the code was valid when running it in the valgrind, without these addition. In this code `index_map()` returns a `cell* w->map+y_offset + x_offset`

I read in several other posts that this might have to do with allocating the integer values and integer pointers again seperatly like this (I tried to do this on the part that gave the Invalid write error):

```
world->map = malloc(sizeof(cell)*rows*cols);
for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols;j++)
    {
       cell* cell = index_map(world, j, i); //cell8 is world->map + offset
       cell->type = malloc(sizeof(celltype);
       *(cell->type) = CELL_DIRT;
       cell->owner =  malloc(sizeof(int);
       *(cell->type) = 0;
    }
}
```

When trying to compile this code, the folllowing error appears:

"`invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘unsigned int’)
  *(cell->type) = 0;`
"

These are the structs I used:

cell struct:

```
typedef struct{
    celltype type;
    unsigned int owner;
} cell;
```

worldmap struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    cell* map;
    unsigned int rows; 
    unsigned int cols;
    int players;
    int* score;
    int* playerturns;
} worldmap;
```

The cell struct remains unchanged and the worldmap struct previously only consisted of `cell* map`, `unsigned int rows` and `unsigned int cols`.

EDIT
index_map code:

```
cell* index_map(worldmap* w, int x, int y)
{   
    cell* place;
    place = w->map + x*w->cols + y;
    return place;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `index_map` cos that seems to be the source of the original bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valgrind error is basically saying that you're accessing memory beyond the bounds of the map you've allocated. And now that you've included the `index_map` function it's quite clear why too.

Imagine if your map is 5 columns by 2 rows - so 10 cells in size. That means the most x and y could be are 4 and 1. Your function calculates 4*5+1 to return the 21st cell... the code to work it out should be this

```
place = w->map + x*w->rows + y;
```

or

```
place = w->map + x + y*w->cols;
```

which would give you 4*2+1 or 4+1*5 = the 9th cell.

As for the the other problems you mention, you don't need to allocate memory for those values because they're not pointers. For example

```
cell->owner =  malloc(sizeof(int);
```

`cell->owner` is an unsigned int so you can just do `cell->owner = 10;` to assign it a value.

As well as that you don't need to de-reference them twice to use them either - the `*(cell->owner)` is overkill and just `cell->owner` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

- `cell->type = malloc(sizeof(celltype);` type is not a pointer. Do you malloc for `cell` itself? What is `index_max`?
- `cell* cell` Using the same name for the type and the variable isn't a brilliant idea.
- `*(cell->type)` is nonsense. Either use `cell->type` or `(*cell).type` (former is more readable).
- Overall, you are using malloc in several places where it doesn't seem to make any sense, and you could just use plain variables instead.
- Where do you `free()` all of this? Valgrind might become upset if you don't.

And so on.